# Polymer google map component not loading tiles in android / cordova

Tags: google-maps, cordova, polymer

I created a simple Polymer component that utilizes the google map component. Then, using the cordova command line tool, I wrapped it in an android app. Most of it works well but unfortunately the google-map component renders improperly, only showing tiles in the top left corner.

I would very much appreciate any insight into why this is happening, and if there are any workarounds, shivs, or polyfills that I can use to mitigate this issue.

**Note:** I do see similar questions here saying to call map.resize() - it would be great if I were able to this in the recommended best practice way for Polymer.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of google-map Polymer element rendering improperly on android/cordova]

Code from my component:

```
<polymer-element name="wh-admin">
  <template>
    <style>
      ::host {}
    </style>

    <core-scaffold fit>
      <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
        <core-toolbar></core-toolbar>
        <core-menu theme="core-light-theme" id="main_menu" selected="0">
          <core-item icon="dns" label="Table View"></core-item>
          <core-item icon="file-map" label="Map View"></core-item>
        </core-menu>
      </core-header-panel>

      <div tool>Water Hero Administration</div>

      <core-animated-pages selected="{{ $.main_menu.selected }}" fit>
        <section>
          <sortable-table columns='["fruit","alice","bill","casey"]' data='[
                  [ "apple", 4, 10, 2 ],
                  [ "banana", 0, 4, 0 ],
                  [ "grape", 2, 3, 5 ],
                  [ "pear", 4, 2, 8 ],
                  [ "strawberry", 0, 14, 0 ] ]'>
          </sortable-table>
        </section>
        <section>
          <google-map latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892" minZoom="9" maxZoom="11" fit id="map"></google-map>
        </section>
      </core-animated-pages>
    </core-scaffold>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({});
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Please check Google Maps web components code here: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map and some tutorials here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OJ7ih8EE7s&index=5&list=PLy1YG3u6yVCRuaxVRRZw7-vv3VxY2Vhk6